# How to set application icon on native link sharing popup in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to add application icon on native **Android** and **iOS** link sharing popup in Unity

Currently i'm using yasirkula native plugin.
https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeShare

I have tried many ways but none of it worked for me.
[i need this type of app icon add in this(native share) popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TCJY.jpg)